# Would OpenSource like some other reposted SO questions?

Tags: discussion, migration

Last year, someone on Meta.SO posted [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327056/can-we-rescue-the-information-in-this-question-somehow) to save a perfectly good SO thread about licensing.

SO has a LOT of these types of questions which are decidedly off-topic. But they're still some great questions with great answers. I had [suggested this on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343219/migrating-older-open-source-licensing-questions-to-opensource-se) but was instructed to ask if you guys would actually want these questions and answers in the first place. It would take some coordination, but I think it could benefit the community here. These are all closed on SO (and I would imagine some are historically locked) so they don't really help us.

So is there any interest in this?

**Note** This isn't some mass-migration proposal. The idea here is to cherry pick those topics that would actually be beneficial here as opposed to SO. Questions closed for other reasons (i.e. Opinion based) would not qualify

Answer (score 2):

If you're confident you can pick stuff that's on-topic, and you're willing to dedicate the time to *fully fixing* those questions before they come here (if they need to be fixed at all, that is), then go right ahead!

Our purpose here is to build up a library of good Q&A. If you can contribute to that goal by moving good quality stuff here, that's awesome - it doesn't have to be something you want answered.

Two things to take note of:

- This is not a high-traffic site. At all. Try not to flood the front page with stuff coming in from SO - probably one a week at most is OK.
- Make sure you're attributing the original authors correctly, as required by CC BY-SA 3.0.

Comment: This would be strictly curated. But there's clearly an interest. The [undeleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419923/can-gpl-be-re-licensed) from earlier today proves people are wanting this stuff to hang around. I'd rather see it live here than just rot on SO. It also helps point people here as opposed to getting those questions closed

Answer (score 1):

The Stack Exchange software won't allow you to migrated really old questions, so it would have to be reposted.

I would say that you should only repost a question if you're genuinely after an answer and you don't think the answers it has at SO are good enough.

Comment: To understand why this needs to be done, the questions are off-topic on SO. As such, they are all closed. Which means they can be deleted. So all of those good answers (which are useful here) just go away. Or you hope for a historical lock

Comment: @Machavity It's actually very rare for well-received off-topic questions to be deleted. If the question or one or two of the answers have a few upvotes they're not going to be deleted.